# How to remove the data from array? : Python

Tags: python, rethinkdb

This is the data saving in my rethinkdb database. And I save the data for 
`addtowatchlater` is array. I use ember.js for frontend and tornado for 
backend and database for rethinkdb.

```
{
    "accesstoken": "ajflasjjfasjfjasfasdfjasjflsajjfas" ,

    "addtowatchlater": [
        {
            "beatdescription":  "aa" ,
            "beatname":  "aa" ,
            "categoryname":  "DJ" ,
            "filename":  "asfasdfasdfasdfa" ,
            "id":  "423423454352342344545423434" ,
            "price":  "aa" ,
            "soldout":  "No" ,
            "stamp":  "1510244267000" ,
            "userid":  "816fbfe8-ea81-4198-98f0-5fb0db01e25e"
        },
        {
            "beatdescription":  "aa" ,
            "beatname":  "aa" ,
            "categoryname":  "DJ" ,
            "filename":  "asfasdfasdfasdfa" ,
            "id":  "423423454352342344545423434" ,
            "price":  "aa" ,
            "soldout":  "No" ,
            "stamp":  "1510244267000" ,
            "userid":  "816fbfe8-ea81-4198-98f0-5fb0db01e25e"}] ,


            "id":  "et4545er5454354354354353" ,

            "role":  "user" ,

            "status":  "Active" ,
        }
```

I want to remove one json data from `addtowatchlater` array field. When I 
remove I want like this for example.

```
{
    "accesstoken": "ajflasjjfasjfjasfasdfjasjflsajjfas" ,

    "addtowatchlater": [
        {
            "beatdescription": "aa" , 
            "beatname": "aa" , 
            "categoryname": "DJ" , 
            "filename": "asfasdfasdfasdfa" , 
            "id": "423423454352342344545423434" , 
            "price": "aa" , 
            "soldout": "No" , 
            "stamp": "1510244267000" , 
            "userid": "816fbfe8-ea81-4198-98f0-5fb0db01e25e"
        }
    ] ,

    "id": "et4545er5454354354354353" ,

    "role": "user" ,

    "status": "Active" , 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the data comes as a XML file ? if so you can see the data from the front end then you can easily by using .removedata() in jquery.

Please refer the url attatched. if you can elaborate your problem more , then can revisit again,

Here's [a link] 
http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/02/remove-item-from-array-using-jquery.html

https://api.jquery.com/removeData/

Comment: Can i remove the data in backend with using python. Because in python it will be more easy for me bro. Thanks.please help me.

Comment: This is not a jQuery question

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the JSON object to a Python dictionary. Now you can do anything you want with that data easily.

Let's say your data looks like this:

```
{
    "a": [
        {
            "p": 1, 
            "q": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 3,
            "y": 4
        }
    ],
}
```

And you want to remove an item from the the array `a`, you can do it like this:

```
import json

data_dict = json.loads(data) # convert data to python dict

data_dict['a'].pop(0) # remove first item from array `a`

# you can convert data_dict back to json if you want
data = json.dumps(data_dict)
```